# Need to select closest item on table

Tags: jquery, css

I need to hide the `"lblItemPrice"` div when I click the `"btnEdit"` button.I need to get the `closest` div which having `"lblItemPrice"` class.

I have tried like this,But not working.

```
 $('.btnEdit').die('click').live('click', function () {
     $(this).closest('.lblItemPrice').hide();
 });
```

**HTML**

```
<table class="invoice" id="invoiceList">

    <tbody>

        <tr class="">

            <td class="value" id="pricetd">
                <div id="itemPriceDiv">
                    <div class="lblItemPrice">
                        $2.00
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" id="editPrice" name="editPrice" placeholder="edit price">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="value">
                $2.00
            </td>
            <td>

                <button class="btnEdit actionButton secondaryButton short" type="button">
                    Edit</button>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `die` and `live` are deprecated. please use the delegate versions of `.on()` and `.off()` instead.

Comment: @ThiefMaster My version of jquery is 1.7.1.So no problem with the live method here.

Comment: If you are using jquery 1.7+ then you cant use live and die but on and off.

Comment: Well you can use it but it's still deprecated!

Comment: @ThiefMaster I have tried with on and off,but unfortunately it's not working with my version of jquery (1.7.1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just find your `lblItemPrice` inside clicked item's parent:

```
$(this).parents('tr').find('.lblItemPrice').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this,

```
 $(this).closest('tr').find('.lblItemPrice').hide();
```